# Override View strategy for specific action

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a application where we using AbstractRestfulController and Json strategy. ( We have a straight requirement for using this approach ). So all our request done through jQuery Ajax with json. Now I have a specific requirement for download a pdf file stored on server. I want to use php/zend headers for download file instead of exposing actual http path for file.

Is there would be any solution for this following Restful approach. I am thinking of override view strategy for specific action, but don't know how ?

I will have a final approach for using a Default AbstractActionController for specific module and placed my code into that. But if it would be the only solution I have (As moving current module specific code into another module is look like a bad idea )?

Comment: Look like I did less R & D for this question before. As simple setting a normal non-rest router and corresponding action in Controller did the action. So My Restful controller doing both type of actions REST actions through main router rule, While non-rest action through custom routes in module.config.php. So no need for any changes in Module.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below an example of adding your own view strategyr, you can see examples in the docs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

It's easy to modify the example to check for a given controller / action if that's the way you want to go.

```
<?php
namespace Application;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        // Register a "render" event, at high priority (so it executes prior
        // to the view attempting to render)
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'registerJsonStrategy'), 100);
    }

    public function registerJsonStrategy($e)
    {
        $app          = $e->getTarget();
        $locator      = $app->getServiceManager();
        $view         = $locator->get('Zend\View\View');
        $phpStrateogy = $locator->get('PhpRendererStrategy');
        // or any you have setup in your config...
        $jsonStrategy = $locator->get('ViewJsonStrategy');

        $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
        /* @var $routeMatch \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch */
        $routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
        if($routeName == 'myroute') {
            // possible change layout?
            //$controller->layout('app/layout/new_layout');
            // Attach strategy, which is a listener aggregate, at high priority
            //$view->getEventManager()->attach($jsonStrategy , 100);
            $view->getEventManager()->attach($phpStrateogy, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just return a different type of ViewModel, if both Strategies are enabled you can change the strategy used by returning a different model inside your controller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // will use JsonRenderer
    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array('bob'));

    // Will use PHPRenderer
    return new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array('bob'));
}
```

Comment: I tried out your code, but method registerJsonStrategy never called. I think, As ViewJsonStrategy is enabled in module.config.php, So render event is never called.

Comment: that was just an example, it wasn't meant to be used as is, it's just an example of how you can add a new strategy.
you could probably use other events too such as dispatch.

Comment: if there's already a jsonViewStrategy with a higher priority then that will be called first, try using a smaller priority number etc

Comment: I already using ViewJsonStrategy into strategies part of module.config.php as all controller using REST pattern by default. I need to allow PhpRendererStrategy for particular method which I intend to use for a downloading file.

Comment: then replace the jsonStrategy with the particular strategy (PHP) you have inside your service config, and change the code to reflect this. Also try a lower priority in the attach method to make sure it comes before the other strategies.

Comment: Ok code is working fine, Just some route name conflicts make problems. I am thinking of other approach if multiple route rules should be allowed for PhpRenderer without using conditional IF or SWITCH in module.php. But still, it is better and only available answer till now.

Comment: You can get the controller and action name from the RouteMatch object, which you can add into your conditional statement ;-)

Comment: I think if you have Both strategies enabled in the config the correct one will be chosen if you return JsonModel or ViewModel inside your controller/action.